# Java, infinite if statement

Tags: java

I'm writing a program for rental car agency (school project) and there is a discount received if you are a member and for every week you book the car you get the amount of weeks times the base price of the car. Is there a way to make code that will allow you to put an infinite number of days? So far I have it up to 2 weeks but what if they want it for 28 days, or 35 etc.?

```
if (Member == 0) {

} else if (Days < 7 ) {
    Discount = Car * 0;
    System.out.println("Club Member Discount:" + "$ " + Discount);
} else if (Days < 14) {
    Discount = Car * -1 ; 
    System.out.println("Club Member Discount:" + "$ " + Discount);
}
```

Comment: You should check if `Days` is divisible by 7, and if it is, do the division and the number you get minus the decimal is the discount.

Comment: I don't think you have to check at all.  Just divide `Days` by seven.  The integer part of the result is the number of weeks and used to calculate discount.   This is a simple exercise to see if the student understands how division and integers work in a computer.

Comment: This really isn't a site for answering homework questions... Look at how Java divides integers. Note that i / 7 returns the result without a remainder. That would tell you how many times to apply the discount.

Comment: This may even be a place to use `%`

Comment: Please note naming conventions. In Java, all variable and method names should be in `camelCase`, not `PascalCase` (which is used for class names), nor `snake_case`. So `member`, `days`, `car` and `discount` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `days` is an integer type (`int`, `long`, *etc*.), a relatively fast way to do it is:

```java
int discount = (-days/7)*car;
```

Just switch `int` to the type of `car`.

Answer (score -1):

Just divide `Days` by 7, and you'll get your discount.

```
discountAmount = Math.floor(Days / 7);
```

Now Discount_amt will equal the amount of weeks the person has been a member.

Now, you can calculate `Discount` without any IF statements.

```
if (Member == 0) {

} else {
    Discount = Car * (discountAmount * -1);
    System.out.println("Club Member Discount:" + "$ " + Discount);
}
```

There is another added benefit to this, being that you can create a max discount.

```
} else {
    if(discountAmount > 3) discountAmount = 3;
    Discount = Car * (discountAmount * -1);
    System.out.println("Club Member Discount:" + "$ " + Discount);
}
```